# Creating an oracle databe link - ora-12154 error

Tags: sql, oracle, database-link

I am trying to create an oracle DB-Link like so:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK test5
CONNECT TO bla IDENTIFIED BY bla
USING 'bli';

select * from dual@test5
```

In my tnsname.ora:

```
NPGPROD =
(DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.10.190.11)(PORT = 1521))
  )
(CONNECT_DATA =
  (SERVICE_NAME = bli)
)
)
```

I recieve :ora-12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Why is that, i couldnt rind an answer on google. is there another file i need to update?

Answer (score 0):

try to modify your statement like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK test5
CONNECT TO bla IDENTIFIED BY bla
USING 'NPGPROD';
```